# Single Quote added automatically in front of numeric data when importing CSV file to Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

When I import a csv file to Google spreadsheet a single quote get added in front of all numeric data.
How can I remove that ?

[image: screenshoot]

I using import option from file menu

[image: screenshoot]

Comment: Are u physically importing a csv file or using importdata function from a live/static url endpoint?

Comment: @AuriellePerlmann I am using import option in file menu

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. right-click the column letter (on columns with numbers)
2. press `Ctrl+F` to invoke Google Sheets Search
3. to the right of the search box, click the `⋮` vertical 3 dots button
   to invoke the `Find and replace` window
4. in the `Find` box, put the `'` single quote (no space after)
5. leave the `Replace` box empty
6. click the `Replace all` button (on the bottom)

That should do the trick

Comment: I got "No matches found" when I tried to find and replace.

Answer (score 0):

put a column in notepad ++ [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zkq0y.png)

make replace, and return column to GD

Answer (score 0):

For me "Find and Replace" didn't work since those single quotes are not found by it.

I could only get rid of the single quotes by formatting affected cells/column as an integer numeric one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open "**Find and Replace**" Dialog. (Shortcut: **CTRL+H** | Menu: EDIT > Find and Replace)
2. Find: `^'` (Explanation: Regular expression `^` (caret sign) indicate that the next character `'` must be appear at the start, without this it will match `Ronnie O'Sullivan`)
3. Tick: `Search using regular expressions` (You can ignore the "Match case" checkbox, as we're not searching for alphabets. It is automatically checked since it is using regex.)
4. Tick: `Also search within formulas`.
5. Click "**Replace All**" Button

[image]